# Spark: unpersist RDDs for which I have lost the reference

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I unpersist RDD that were generated in an MLlib model for which I don't have a reference?

I know in pyspark you could unpersist all dataframes with `sqlContext.clearCache()`, is there something similar but for RDDs in the scala API? Furthermore, is there a way I could unpersist only some RDDs without having to unpersist all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can call

```
val rdds = sparkContext.getPersistentRDDs(); // result is Map[Int, RDD]
```

and then filter values to get this value that you want (1) :

```
rdds.filter (x => filterLogic(x._2)).foreach (x => x._2.unpersist())
```

(1) - written by hand, without compiler - sorry if there's some error, but there shouldn't be ;)

Comment: Is there any equivalent command like `val rdds = sparkContext.getPersistentRDDs(); // result is Map[Int, RDD]` in pySpark?

Comment: @KostasGeorgiou No, there is no such function in PySpark. Please see this ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2141 You can only query RESTful API for RDD ids

Comment: I just solved it using the jvm spark context. This is the equivalent: 
`for (id, rdd) in sc._jsc.getPersistentRDDs().items():
        rdd.unpersist()`